Применить стили к родительскому блоку
В css, как указать, что необходимо применить стили к родительскому блоку?

Что вы имеете ввиду?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has но это относительно свежий селектор, так что внимательно смотрите на поддержку браузерами.

псевдокласс :has() в CSS предназначен для изменения стилей родительских элементов в зависимости от наличия определенных дочерних элементов. Он позволяет задать стили для родителя, если внутри него присутствуют определенные дочерние элементы, будь то с классами, тегами, атрибутами или другими характеристиками.
Вот несколько примеров использования :has():
а) С классом:
/* Изменение фона, если у .card есть элемент с классом .highlight */
.card:has(.highlight) {
  background-color: green;
}

б) Без использования класса:
/* Изменение стиля, если у .card есть элемент <p> */
.card:has(p) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

в) С атрибутом:
/* Изменение стиля, если у .card есть <img> с атрибутом alt */
.card:has(img[alt]) {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

г) С использованием структурных селекторов:
/* Изменение стиля, если первый дочерний элемент .card — это <h2> */
.card:has(:first-child h2) {
  padding: 30px;
}

❗поддержка :has() может быть ограничена в некоторых браузерах.

рекомендуется проверять текущую поддержку и совместимость с браузерами перед использованием


.card {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}


/* Изменение фона, если у card есть элемент с классом highlight */

.card:has(.highlight) {
  background-color: green;
}
<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Это обычное содержимое</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="content highlight">
    <p>Это содержимое родителя :has</p>
  </div>
</div>




В Firefox со 121 версии есть (сейчас актуальная 128)

псевдокласс :has() в CSS позволяет управлять дочерними элементами. - не позволяет

Можно задать родительскому элементу класс и обратиться к нему в css-файле
